# Ajax Load page in javascript code not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am loading a page using the code below.
But the javascript codes on the page do not work.

Code:

```
$(".tikla").click(function() {
    $(".popup").load('../../game/set.php .popup-icdis');
});
```

But if I use the code below, my javascript codes in the page are working.

```
 $(".tikla").click(function() {
        $(".popup").load('../../game/set.php');
    });
```

This time 1 page loads 20-30 times.

When I click the button, I want it to load the page 1 time. And the loaded page has javascript codes that need to work on them.

I'm waiting for your help.
Thank you from now.

Comment: The first one is not a valid url

Comment: the url addresses are correct.
what are you talking about?

Comment: Instead of using CSS class for page fragment target (`.popup-icdis`), please try to use an ID like `#popup-icdis`. But don't forget to modify the target page as well.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz set.php in 
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert("Test");
</script> code not working.

Ajax page load success, But the javascript code in set.php is not working.

Comment: When you load a fragment of a remote page using a selector 'ie `.popup-icdis`', the `script` portion will not be loaded therefore it will not be called.

Comment: $(".popup").load('../../game/set.php');
With this piece of code, the page loads smoothly. But he throws requests 20-30 times in the background